# Create HTML code that isn't parsed by browser (for reuse)

Tags: html, css

I have a snippet of HTML code that I want to reuse throughout my page.

```
        <div class="gmail-message-container">
            <span class="trim-text">
                <span class="gmail-sender">
                    some.email@some.domain (Some Name)
                </span>:
            </span>
            <br>
            <b><span class="trim-text gmail-title">Some title</span></b>
            <br>
            <span class="trim-text gmail-summary">Some summary text goes here</span>
        </div>
```

How can I make the `gmail-message-container` serve as html element that isn't being shown and can be grabbed by JavaScript and appended to multiple places?

The element is assigned certain CSS rules that affect the element based on number of elements inside the container, hence I cannot just do `display: none;`, as it will count in the element I'm trying to copy.

Comment: @apokryfos read the question more carefully: "I cannot just do display: none;"

Comment: Do `style='display: none;'` in a container. Don't make life hard for yourself.

Comment: You may want to consider a template engine such as  http://handlebarsjs.com/ or https://github.com/janl/mustache.js

Comment: Experiment with putting it in a custom script tag: `<script type="text/my-template-language">`. This won't be interpreted by the browser as anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

a common pattern for such purposes is to use

```
<script type="text/template" id="template">
// your html goes here
</script>
```

`text/template` prevents browser from parsing the insides of `<script>` tag (you can use something different, it is only required not to use `text/javascript` to do so)

you can grab your template later by using `document.getElementById('template').innerHTML`

Comment: This seems like an approach that will solve many of my other problems too. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can put it in `script` tag.

```
<script id="your-template-id" type="text/template">
    <div class="gmail-message-container">
        ....      
    </div>
</script>
```

Browser doesn't know what type `text/template` means and doesn't parse it.
You can after grab contents of this template by id, for example:

```
var tpl = document.querySelector('#your-template-id').innerHTML;
```

This aproach is used in some js frameworks, like [Backbone](https://www.sitepoint.com/backbone-basics-models-views-collections-templates/#rendering-data-with-views-templates).

====

There is also [html5](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/) tag `template`, that you can use and it was explicitly designed to hold templates.

Answer (score 3):

**One possible solution:**

Place it outside the container in a hidden div, which has an ID:

```
<div id="message_template" style="display:none">
    <div class="gmail-message-container">
        <span class="trim-text">
            <span class="gmail-sender">
                some.email@some.domain (Some Name)
            </span>:
        </span>
        <br>
        <b><span class="trim-text gmail-title">Some title</span></b>
        <br>
        <span class="trim-text gmail-summary">Some summary text goes here</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then use Javascript to clone the content of the hidden div into your container.

JQuery solution:

```
var newItem = $("#message_template").find(".gmail-message-container").clone();

newItem.appendTo($("yourcontainer"));
```

where `yourcontainer` is the selector of the container which will have the `.gmail-message-container` items.

**Another solution,** very similar to the one above, is to specify it as a template:

Specify your snippet as a template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="your-template-name">
    <div class="gmail-message-container">
        <span class="trim-text">
            <span class="gmail-sender">
                some.email@some.domain (Some Name)
            </span>:
        </span>
        <br>
        <b><span class="trim-text gmail-title">Some title</span></b>
        <br>
        <span class="trim-text gmail-summary">Some summary text goes here</span>
    </div>
</script>

var template = document.querySelector('#your-template-name').innerHTML;
```